# Xpath not finding the element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-2.0

Below Xpath is not able to find the element.

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]

WebElement addempid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]//input"));addempid.sendKeys("0259");
```

Comment: Post the URL and the code you've tried so far.

Comment: This is the code i am trying                                                                           
WebElement addempid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input[1]/"));addempid.sendKeys("0259");

Comment: this is the x path ------- //*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input

Comment: Without the URL or full Html source, it is difficult to debug.

Comment: below is the website which i am doing automation for emp id field           - https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/pim/addEmployee- username: Admin Pass: admin123

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relative xpath that would work //div[.//label[text()='Employee Id']]/div/input